# How to use SASS to parse a list of all CSS selectors in an .scss file?

Tags: ruby, sass

I'd like to programmatically parse an .scss file to generate a flat list of selectors that are used in that file, mostly as basis for some static code analysis.

In SASS terms, I'm looking for a way to get a list of all `Sass::Tree::RuleNode` for a given .scss file.

So far I'm using `Sass::Engine.for_file` to create a Tree. Then, in order to use `Sass::Tree::RuleNode.resolved_rules` on the individual Nodes I have to use `Tree::Visitors::Cssize`, according to the documentation. But somewhere in there is a (probably simple) error.

```
require 'sass'

sass_engine = Sass::Engine.for_file('files/examples.scss',{
  :style => :compact,
  :load_paths => ['files'],
  :syntax => :scss,
})

tree = sass_engine.to_tree

Sass::Tree::Visitors::Cssize.visit(tree)

tree.each do |node|
  if node.is_a? Sass::Tree::RuleNode
    puts node.resolved_rules
  end
end
```

This is the error and stacktrace I'm getting:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:186:in `visit_prop': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:30:in `block in visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:52:in `with_parent'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:29:in `visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:201:in `visit_rule'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:30:in `block in visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:52:in `with_parent'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:29:in `visit_children'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:65:in `visit_root'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:21:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:24:in `visit'
    ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/sass-3.2.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/cssize.rb:6:in `visit'
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Maybe a stacktrace would help someone to help you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the Sass gem codebase but was able to get this working (without crashing, at least) by following the code example of the **Cssize** class from sass gem's `sass/tree/root_node.rb` file, which has:

```
  # Runs the dynamic Sass code *and* computes the CSS for the tree.
  # @see #to_s
  def render
    Visitors::CheckNesting.visit(self)
    result = Visitors::Perform.visit(self)
    Visitors::CheckNesting.visit(result) # Check again to validate mixins
    result, extends = Visitors::Cssize.visit(result)
    Visitors::Extend.visit(result, extends)
    result.to_s
  end
```

Taking this code snippet and applying it to your script, I get:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sass'

sass_engine = Sass::Engine.for_file('files/examples.scss',{
  :style => :compact,
  :load_paths => ['files'],
  :syntax => :scss,
})

tree = sass_engine.to_tree

Sass::Tree::Visitors::CheckNesting.visit(tree)
result = Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit(tree)
Sass::Tree::Visitors::CheckNesting.visit(result)
result, extends = Sass::Tree::Visitors::Cssize.visit(result)
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Extend.visit(result, extends)

result.each do |node|
  if node.is_a? Sass::Tree::RuleNode
    puts node.resolved_rules
  end
end
```